# HTTP Status 404 in SSH+MVC web application

Tags: ssh, jdk6

### Here is my  configration:

```
Tomcat 6<br/>
jdk1.6<br/>
MyEclipse 
Win 7
HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
```

> I have a Dynamic Web Project set up in MyEclipse titled "ch21" with following structure. The web application works well local.But when I upload it to website.Then I can't call any jsp file.Such as index.jsp ,regist.jsp.
>    The error message is following.

### HTTP Status 404

```
message
description The requested resource () is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

### struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="gb2312"></constant>

<package name="struts2" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="regist" class="regAction">
            <result name="success" >/login.jsp</result> 
            <result name="input">/regist.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/regist.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

> I added the following in web.xml.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>register.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

> I  call http://example.net/index.jsp .But It can't work.
>       The error message :HTTP Status 404 .

Comment: No. Just no. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again.

Comment: when I close project,eclipse gives an error:"Lack of disk space",and I had to close the myeclipse.
then, I can't  open the myeclipse. I built a new folder and rebuilt the project,but  it gave the above error..  thank you very much

Comment: Could I delete my question and restart

Comment: @L Linda Probably, if you don't get question banned. Just make sure to include **all** relevant information on your first try, usually the first couple of minutes decide if you are going to get help or not. Make sure to read **everything** in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the sub-articles in the yellow box on the right. Make sure you proof read the question or if your English isn't good enough ask someone to proof read it for you. Include enough code for a [mcve], state a clear problem, what you have tried to solve it, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search other questions and then just now I asked the hosting.He help me and updata a jar(he didn't tell me detail),and he solve the question.Thank you very much!